# Whether progressive web app supports offline on desktop? If no why?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I am interested in developing a progressive web app.I want to know whether it supports offline in desktop.

Comment: You have it backwards. The browser has to support PWAs. PWAs don't support any particular category of platform.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, one of the features of Progressive Web Apps that differentiate them from regular web apps is that they work offline, whether you’re using your browser on your desktop or your mobile device. If you’re developing a Progressive Web App, you can ensure that your app works offline with the use of service workers and the Cache API. You can read more about how to do that here: https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/caching-files-with-service-worker

Answer (score -1):

Desktop browsers support the Cache API just as mobile ones.

You can check here: https://jakearchibald.github.io/isserviceworkerready/#caches

Answer (score -3):

Because the progressive Web apps on mobile use the local storage mechanism on mobile and it keeps the data updated by asynchronously interacting with actual backend APIs using delta calls.
However on a browser you do not have such facility to keep this much data on local storage. Also you can not enforce a user to install a local mysql per se. .

Comment: This is not true, you can of course store data in LocalStorage or IndexedDB on desktop browsers.

Comment: "Also you can not enforce a user to install a local mysql per se" — What does that have to do with PWAs?

Comment: The limit of data that can be stored on browsers is:
Browser    | Chrome   | Opera    | Firefox    | Safari      | IE
Version    | 40       | 27       | 34         | 6-8         | 9-11
Available  | 10MB     | 10MB     | 10MB       | 5MB         | 10MB
this in no way is comparable to the mobile's local storage which is much higher and thats what is my point here..

Comment: "Also you can not enforce a user to install a local mysql per se" was just for fun. . point was that browser does not have the luxury of local storage as much as a mobile app has. .

Comment: indexed db of browser can be used however the usage would have its implications